# More efficient way of doing destroy_all in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, performance

Is there a quicker way of doing destroy all in rails?

I'm asking this because rails does an individual delete sql query per record.

For example calling destroy all on a search for 4 records would then run 4 delete sql commands.

```
Blerg.where("created_at > yesterday").destroy_all (4 results)
```

then calles…

```
DELETE FROM "blergs" WHERE "blergs"."id" = $1  [["id", 197782]]
```

4 times.

Is there a way to get it into one sql command?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can allways call

```
Blerg.where("created_at > yesterday").delete_all
```

This gives only one query:

```
DELETE FROM "blergs" WHERE (created_at > '2012-11-26 16:27:56.678872')
```

Note that this does not call any callbacks on the objects which are to be deleted.

Comment: The callbacks is an important point.  If you have any :dependent => :destroy relations involved, they will not be deleted as well.

Comment: Yeah, anyone looking for this answer should take note of no callbacks, it's pretty important.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do

```
Blerg.delete_all("created_at > '2012-11-01 00:00:00'")
```

which is more succinct.  It executes one SQL statement.